# HTML dropdown list when a key pressed the list goes to the keyed item

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some difficulties trying to find a solution for my drop down list, the list is quite long and I need it to listen when a key is pressed to scroll to the matched key.

This is my drop down list:

```
<div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-right">
        <button class="w3-button">Services &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border" style="max-height:400px; overflow:auto; color:blue">
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Accountants/Auditors</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Advertising</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Air Condition</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Airlines</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Ambulances</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Antiques</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Arquitects</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Art</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Arts and Crafts</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Auctioneers</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Audio Visual</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Automobile</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Baby Sitting</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Bakers</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Banking Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Barbers</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Bars/Nightclubs</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Bicycles</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Boats/Catamarans</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Book Stores</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Boutiques</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Car rentals</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Catering Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Cellular Phones</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Chiropractors</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Cinemas</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Cleaners</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Coffe Shops</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Computers</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Contractors</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Convenience Stores</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Cosmetic Surgery</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Costume Jewelry</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Couriers</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Dance/Ballet</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Day Care/Nurseries</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Decoration</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Dental/Oral Care</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Duty-Free Shops</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Electricians</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Embroidery</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Equipment Rentals</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Eye Care</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Eyelashes</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Fitness Instructors</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Florists</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Funeral Homes</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Garden Centres/Landscaping</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Gardeners</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Gift Shops</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Golf</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Gymnastics</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Gyms/Health Clubs</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Hairdressers/Beauty Salon</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Hardware</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Horse Riding</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Hotels/Resorts</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Insurance</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Interior Decoration</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Janitors</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Landscaping</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Laundermats</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Launguage Centres</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lawyers</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Limousine</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Locksmiths</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Nails</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Party Planners</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Pest Control</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Pet Shops</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Photo Copies</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Photographers</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Physical Therapists</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Plants</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Plumbers</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Pressure Cleaners</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Printeries</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Real Estate</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Rental Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Restaurants</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Schools</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Scuba Diving</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Security</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Sewing/Seamstress</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Souvenirs</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Sports Bars</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Swimming Instructors</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Tailors</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Tattooing</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Taxicabs</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Tennis</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Tourist Attractions</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Tours and Taxi Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Translators /Interpreters</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Travel Agencies</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Trucks/Moving Experts</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Tutoring</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Upholstery Cleaning</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Watches </a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Wedding Cakes</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Wedding Planners</a>

            </div>
        </div>
```

What can i do to make this happen, I have had no luck in finding a solution

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: no php, json, ajax. Removed those tags.

Comment: what library is that?

Comment: it is not dropdown list that usually we built with `<select><option></option></select>` the behavior you want is by default with traditional dropdown list

Comment: The HTML code for the list has been posted I don't know how to proceed from there

Comment: I don't think [that framework](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp) with [this dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_dropdowns.asp) can do what you want.

Comment: You might want to think about using [Select2](https://select2.org/selections) instead.

Comment: or just use a normal `<select "w3-select">` - [the docs](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_input.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {

  var currentFocus;

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;

      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;

      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

          b = document.createElement("DIV");

          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
 
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
      
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {

        currentFocus++;

        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { 

        currentFocus--;

        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
 
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
      });
}


var list = ["Accountants", "Auditors","Advertising", "Air", "Condition" ,"Airlines", "Barbers" ,"Bars","Nightclubs"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), list);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
</style>
</head>     

<body>

<h2>Autocomplete</h2>

<form autocomplete="off">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myList" placeholder="List">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and add your data in "list" variable

Comment: the OP already has a framework/library running. Implementing a new custommade autocomplete seems a bit overkill to fix a bug.

Comment: I don't know (I asked for it), but `class="w3-button"` and similar once clearly indicate one. The dropdown wouldn't do anything without a library..

Comment: I looked in this site but I didn't find anything about the auto-completion

Comment: The OP actually just wants a select, that jumps to the matching option when pressing a key - as every normal select does.

Comment: ah, so he can just use a regular <select> tag